# Will I get incorrect answers if I don't scale these variables in a MatLab program?

Tags: matlab

I am using the ode45 function to solve a differential equation in MatLab. I have variables for width, height and depth that are each `2 x 10^{-9}` metres and I am using them for volume so I have a term that is `8 x 10^{-27}`. Will I experience precision errors with Matlab due to this?

I am also using a timespan of 0 to `1 x 10^{-9}` if that also makes a difference?

The equation I have is something like

[image]

where `k` is some constant and `t0` is the initial time.

Do I need to scale variables to successfully use the ode45 function to solve this equation?

Comment: I doubt it, as it is only a multiplicative constant for the entire expression. But this is a dark art, don't take my word for granted. You could simply try it to see if there's a difference.

Comment: Since the problem is linear, you can compare `ode45`'s solution to the analytical one.  However, I don't think there will be huge precision errors, but the unscaled problem may be stiff due to the enormity of the RHS.